# When is "this" useful in native JavaScript array methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, this

Beginner-ish question:

Many of the JavaScript native array methods (map, filter, find, forEach, etc) can be reassigned by passing a "this" object to the second argument. I've never seen that used and I'm struggling to come up with any situation where it would be needed.

Every array gets all the native methods by default, so when would it be useful to rebind them?

Comment: Go through this post. I think this is duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/54439040#54439040

Comment: Not really _"reassigned"_. The _`thisArg`_ lets you assign the `this` context for the callback function, otherwise it is `undefined`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description

Comment: Highly recommend viewing https://egghead.io/courses/understand-javascript-s-this-keyword-in-depth course. It will give very good insight into how `this` works.

Comment: As Phil says, the second argument is for setting the `this` value of the callback, not the  array method itself.

Comment: Gotcha - sorry, missed that in the docs. Thanks!